# Android Jetpack Compose Icons doesn't contain some of the material icons

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

There're many oft-used [material icons](https://material.io/resources/icons/) in [androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/Icons) but some are missing. Just as an example there is no [print icon](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=print).

```kotlin
...

import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu  // ok
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Print // error, unresolved reference

@Composable
fun IconsExample() {
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "menu")   // ok
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Print, "print") // error, unresolved reference
}
```

What is the simplest way to use those missing icons in an app?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

There's a separate dependency `material-icons-extended` which contains the full list of material icons, just add it into your app's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
}
```

Now you can use any material icon, for example:

```kotlin
...

import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu  // ok
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Print // ok

@Composable
fun IconsExample() {
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "menu")   // ok
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Print, "print") // ok
}
```

**A note about the artifact size:** Since the artifact contains all material icons for multiple themes, it's a pretty big dependency, 18MB aar as of `1.0.0-alpha10`. There's a [note on maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.material/material-icons-extended) that recommends not to use it directly:

> This module contains all Material icons. It is a very large dependency and should not be included directly.

Сonsidering that most Android projects enable [code shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-code) for release builds, such a large dependency won't affect the release build size but it can affect your debug build and device upload time, though I'm not sure that the influence would be significant. Actually many of [compose samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) use this dependency.

If only a few additional icons are required and you decided not to use `material-icons-extended` artifact, the icons can be easily added into your project resources [using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#materialicon). You can use such resource-icons like this:

```kotlin
...

import com.mycompany.myproject.R
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource

@Composable
fun ResourceIconExample() {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_print_24),
        contentDescription = "print"
    )
}
```

Comment: It seems that Google recommends against including the entire set of extended icons as stated on the [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.material/material-icons-extended). Do you know if we can only add those additional icons that are needed?

Comment: @JesseHill Thank you for the observation. I've updated the answer with some additional information including a sample of an icon which doesn't use `material-icons-extended`, hope it helps!

Comment: please mark this answer as the acceptable one

Comment: I still can't see QuestionMark (https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Aquestion_mark%3A) for example even with the extended dependency...

Comment: Great answer, thanks. To get just a few icons, I made an isolated compose app, included `material_icons_extended`, jumped to definition on the icons I wanted, and copied the code to my project. I put it in our own namespace so I can keep track of which are used etc.  A little cumbersome, but minimal overhead! Each icon  is just a private and a public property, that's it.

Comment: Using `painterResource` is buggy with the AS compose preview, I constantly get render issues (android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0xAAF3D.) and have to recompile, anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: @BarryIrvine I experienced the same problem. But on close inspection, the dependency which I copied from the documentation I believe was `implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended-android:$compose_ui_version"` which also synced without issues. Make sure it is correctly spelled as shown in this answer.

Comment: How about material 3, I know it can be used along with material 2 icon lib. But don't wanna mixed.

Answer (score 3):

**Official response from Google regarding missing icons in material-icons-extended dependency (Feb 5, 2024)**

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>
> The Compose icons are synced
> with the Material Icons set, while the default that is displayed on
> the web is the Material Symbols (there is a drop-down button on the
> left to switch between the two).
>
> At this time, if you want to use symbols, we recommend going the
> manual path. Later in the future we may add built-in support for
> Symbols as well.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/323537650

**So if you want to use icons from https://fonts.google.com/icons you need to import them manually. The material-icons-extended dependency does not contain them all.**

Answer (score 2):

I will add to previous comment that you can  use not only painterResource but ImageVector. That way you can use the same type parameter in composable functions.
[ImageBitmap vs ImageVector](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/compare)

```
val imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_shopping_cart_24)
```